# How to change the q command in qJupyter?

Tags: jupyter, kdb

[image]

I want to change

`Starting Kernel: ['q', 'jupyter_kernel.q' ... ]`

to

`Starting Kernel: ['taskset -c 1,2 ${QHOME}/l64/q', 'jupyter_kernel.q' ... ]`

The debug comes from running :

`jupyter console --kernel=qpk --debug`

which is the standard exec command here :

https://github.com/KxSystems/jupyterq

Comment: Not used Jupyterq in a while but could try changing this file? https://github.com/KxSystems/jupyterq/blob/master/kernelspec/kernel.json

Comment: before or after install ? 
I think i tried after install and no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the file https://github.com/KxSystems/jupyterq/blob/master/kernelspec/kernel.json

```
{
 "argv": [
  "taskset",
  "-c",
  "0,1",
  "q",
  "jupyterq_kernel.q",
  "-cds",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Q (kdb+)",
 "language": "q",
 "env": {"JUPYTERQ_SERVERARGS":"","MPLBACKEND":"Agg"}
}
```

If you have already installed you can ensure Jupyter picks up the changes by reinstalling the kernel:

```
python -m jupyter kernelspec install --user --name=qpk /path/to/kernelspec
```

And you can validate in a notebook with `system"taskset -pc ",string .z.i`:

[image: jupyter output showing taskset]